# Qt Hover ToolButton GIF Not Moving

Tags: qt, button, hover, animated-gif

I have a toolbutton and when I hover over the toolbutton, the GIF is shown but the GIF is not moving (it is an animated GIF).

```
animatedButton->setStyleSheet("ToolButton:hover { background-image: url(../GIF/animated-picture.gif); }");
```

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you set GIF without hover? Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825990/how-to-add-animated-gif-to-a-button?rq=1) post, it may help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I set without hover but the GIF is still not moving. I set a tooltip with the GIF and it's still not moving. I tried to reference to that post, and use `image` instead of `background-image` but it still does not work. I'm not sure if displaying a GIF image is as straight forward as it seems.

Comment: Well, did you try the accepted answer, reediting the GIF? Maybe your GIF is problematic?